# How do I include external libraries using Webpack in a Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack

I've decided I want to use Webpack and Babel to develop my Wordpress theme because I want to support ES6 features and still have my website work on older browsers (IE11), as well as other benefits such as being able to import files so that I don't have to have all of my JS in one big script.js file (e.g. for themes that use WebGL).

It's my first time setting up and using Webpack, I'm pretty sure I have it all set up in the correct way because I followed a few tutorials to do it and it's all working great, but my main question is with using external libraries. I have a couple that I need to use (i.e. Chart.js, Flickity, Magnific Popup, etc...) installed via NPM. I have a main `script.js` file that contains my normal Javascript code and gets bundled into `bundle.min.js` which is the file that is enqueued with Wordpress.

**What is the best way to use external libraries alongside my `script.js` file with webpack?**

At the moment the best solution I came up with is to have my `script.js` file setup in the following way:

```
// Imports
import 'magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js';
import 'flickity/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js';
import 'chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js';



script.js code...
```

When I run `npm run build` it all works fine and babel and uglify js work their magic to minify and make the code work on old browsers, but for some reason I feel like there's a better way to do it because I couldn't find any info online about it.

**Is that the best way to do it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, we don't need to minify/transpile external libraries using babel-loader in webpack (as they already support all browsers internally). For these files, you can use script-loader instead of babel-loader.

One alternative way of importing would be by adding these libraries using npm and importing them where ever required. By this approach, webpack includes these libraries where ever required instead of loading it every time which is unnecessary.

Comment: Okay yeah that's exactly what I thought, thanks for the comment! I'll look into those options some more and come back to you if I need to, would you recommend any method over the other?

Comment: is there any chance you could give an example of how I would use script-loader to have for examlple chart.js loaded before my script.js file?

Comment: We can include it similar to how we include in babel-loader

`{
                test: /public\/js\/lib(.+)\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'script-loader', // For library files to load in window
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: isProduction,
                    },
                },
            },`

Note: dont forget to **exclude these files in babel-loader config**

Comment: Ah okay great I understand now, so I point it to the folder with all of the external libraries JS files in and it will load them before my script file, that makes sense, thanks!